# Advice on AppleScript syntax for adding Apple Mail.app message URL into Calendar.app

Tags: applescript, automator

With a Calendar.app Event open and the cursor in the URL field I can select the Services menu and run this script. It activates Mail.app and asks me to select the message to copy its URL.

I tried to use `keystroke g_url` instead of `set clipboard` and `keystroke "v"` but the entire URL wouldn't get pasted, only "message:" was pasted into calendar.

If anyone has any ideas on how to clean this up and streamline it I would appreciate it.

I have it in an Automator workflow Quick Action.

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        display dialog "Select a Mail message to copy its Message ID" buttons {"Selected", "Cancel"}
        if button returned of result is "Selected" then
            tell application "Mail"
                set theSelectedMessages to selection
                set the selected_message to item 1 ¬
                    of the theSelectedMessages
                set message_id to the message id of the selected_message
                set the clipboard to "message://<" & message_id & ">"
                tell application "Calendar"
                    activate
                end tell
                tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

EDIT:
To clarify. When I try to keystroke a variable, `g_url`, the script does not work.

I receive an error when avoiding the clipboard method.
[image]

EDIT 2"

This code brings the message viewer window forward if it has been miniaturized. Using `activate` and `reopen` will not do so.

```
    tell application "Mail"
        set MainWindow to get id of every window whose name contains "Inbox"
        set miniaturized of window id MainWindow to false
    end tell
```

Comment: Can't figure out why users downvote a question without making a good faith effort to understand the question. Pretty clearly stated that I was getting an error using the syntax and looking for a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor**, with minor modifications to work from within it, and as is as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, under **macOS Catalina**  with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Mail"
    reopen
    activate
end tell

delay 0.25

tell current application
    activate
    set msg to "Select a Mail message to copy its Message ID"
    display dialog msg buttons {"Cancel", "Selected"} default button 1
end tell

if button returned of result is "Selected" then
    tell application "Mail"
        set theSelectedMessages to selection
        set the selectedMessage to item 1 ¬
            of the theSelectedMessages
        set messageID to the message id of the selectedMessage
        set the clipboard to "message://<" & messageID & ">"
    end tell
    tell application "Calendar" to activate
    delay 0.2
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
end if
```

**Notes:**

The *code* in the OP is not structured well having nested `tell` *blocks/statements*  within one another in a manner that is not appropriate. The *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above is properly structured for the *events* that need to take place.

In the first `tell application "Mail"` *block* `reopen` is used so if **Mail** is already opened and without a *window* opened, it opens the default *window*, thus allowing it to be activated for the **user** to make a selection.

The `tell current application` *block* allows the **display dialog** to come to the front, so as not to be hidden under other *windows*.

In the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is all that is in the **Run AppleScript** *action*. The **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* is set to **Workflow receives [no input] in [Calendar]**.

As this is dealing with two *applications* and an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* using a **display dialog**, one might consider adding some additional coding to set the *bounds/position/size* of the *windows* and *dialog box* involved.

If you want to avoid using **the clipboard**, then change the following lines of *code*:

**Change:**

```applescript
set the clipboard to "message://<" & message_id & ">"
```

**To:**

```applescript
set theURL to "message://<" & messageID & ">"
```

**Change:**

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

**To:**

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell front window of process "Calendar"
        if exists pop over 1 then
            set the value of the first text field of pop over 1 ¬
                whose value of attribute "AXPlaceholderValue" is "Add URL" to theURL
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Note that in order to use the modified *code* shown directly above, the **Event** must be showing as a *pop up* and the cursor placed in the **Add URL** *text box*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Mail"
    reopen
    activate
end tell

delay 0.25

tell current application
    activate
    set msg to "Select a Mail message to copy its Message ID"
    display dialog msg buttons {"Cancel", "Selected"} default button 1
end tell

if button returned of result is "Selected" then
    tell application "Mail"
        set theSelectedMessages to selection
        set the selectedMessage to item 1 ¬
            of the theSelectedMessages
        set messageID to the message id of the selectedMessage
        set theURL to "message://<" & messageID & ">"
    end tell
    tell application "Calendar" to activate
    delay 0.2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of process "Calendar"
            if exists pop over 1 then
                set the value of the first text field of pop over 1 ¬
                    whose value of attribute "AXPlaceholderValue" is "Add URL" to theURL
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: The only issue is with avoiding the clipboard. I get an error. Will add to the original post

Comment: Did you try to click on the link that was added to the calendar event to see if it opens the Mail message?

Comment: @John, Sorry, while I did check the link with **the clipboard** I had not checked it with typing the **URL**. I am investing it and will update the answer if I find a solution. However, the answer as currently now posted does do as stated. Thanks. BTW What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @John, I have added back the "If you want to avoid using **the clipboard**, then change the following lines of code:" _section_ with changs to the _code_ that has worked for me in testing.

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina. Any clue why we need to resort to Accessibility features to paste a value stored in a variable, but not if we paste from the clipboard? Thank you!

Comment: @John, RE: "Any clue why we need to resort to Accessibility features to paste a value stored in a variable" --  The modified _code_ is not pasting anything, it's setting the _value_ of and are two entirely different things. -- RE: "but not if we paste from the clipboard" --  As I was not able to quickly determine why `keystroke` wouldn't work, even though the _variable_ had the correct information, I decided to take a different route and found a viable solution to not using **the clipboard**. At some point, how else can it be accomplished is more important then why does _this_ not work.